# How to send a variable to a parameter variable in a PHP function and return its value to javascript using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

I know you cant just send information over to as one is client side and the other server side, but im asking how would I go about to do this.

I have a two dynamic select/option drop down which is echoed from PHP with HTML tags.

If first drop box is selected the second drop box will contain information relevant to the first drop box, for example first drop box (console) second drop box (ps4/xbox one) etc. All this information is stored to a database.

At the moment Im only using javascript to do all this as I manually enter the value to a script as below:

```
case "Christmas":
    var opt = document.createElement("option")
    opt.value = "Lanterns";
    opt.innerHTML = "Lanterns";
    sub.appendChild(opt);
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = "Hanging Decorations";
    opt.innerHTML = "Hanging Decorations";
    sub.appendChild(opt);
    break;
```

PHP for gathering all the option for first drop box

```
while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
    $catName = $row['CAT'];
    $option .= "<option value='$catName'>$catName</option>";
}
```

Echoing information to HTML

```
<select name="Cat" id="Cat" onchange="subCatActivation('')" onclick="realTimeChange(this.id)">
    <option value="title">Main Category</option>
    <?php echo $option?>
</select>
```

I have created a PHP function with a parameter that will have the values of the first drop box:

```
function getSubCat($mainCat){
    $subOption = '';
    $subName = [];
    include"../storeSQL/sql_Connection.php";
    $sql = "SELECT SUB_CAT FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CAT = '$mainCat' GROUP BY SUB_CAT";
    $getQuery = $connection->query($sql);
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
        $subName[$i] = $row['SUB_CAT'];
        $subOption .= "<option value='$subName[$i]'>$subName[$i]</option>";
        echo " " . $subName[$i];
        $i++;
    }
    return $subName;
}
```

I need now to call this function inside my javascript to do the similar validation as the above switch case. But im having trouble sending the information over and then receive return value of that function back.

Comment: The technology you're looking for is called "AJAX".  Take a look at some examples of using AJAX in PHP to get started.

Comment: Ajax loading perhaps? You can POST an object with all the values you need to the PHP page. Like David said as I was typing. Thanks David

Comment: Yeah I know its AJAX.I just dont know how to post it to a parameter in a PHP function

Comment: @Luke: That's why you would start with some tutorials and examples of how to *use* AJAX with PHP.  Passing a value from the client to the server is generally covered by those.  It's good that you already know the technology you want to use, but Stack Overflow does not seek to replace the *many* existing tutorials and examples on the internet.  Start with those.  If you get stuck on a specific problem, we can help with that.

Comment: @David I have given it a try but got stuck, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827301/updating-select-option-elements-value-using-ajax-php-sql