# Updating select/option elements value using AJAX/PHP/SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Little background,

I have a two dynamic select/option drop down which is echoed from PHP using sql queries.

If first drop box is selected the second drop box will contain information relevant to the first drop box, for example first drop box (console) second drop box (ps4/xbox one) etc. All this information is stored to a database.

If user select the first drop box javascript/AJAX sends that information to PHP/server, in PHP I then create a sql query and echo back all the available select/option for the second drop box.

However I am a bit stuck as I am not sure if this is the right way to implement the  tags.

Nothing is showing on the option field.

UPDATED,

The first Drop box is working fine, the problem is the second one, with id sub_cat.

Javascript AJAX:

```
 function subCatActivation(i) {
      var selectedBox = document.getElementById("Cat" + i);
      var val = selectedBox.options[selectedBox.selectedIndex].value;
      var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "parse_receive_select.php";
      hr.open("POST", url, true);

      hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlendcoded");

      hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("opt").innerHTML = return_data;
          }
      }
      hr.send(val);
 }
```

HTML

```
<select name="Cat" id="Cat" onchange="subCatActivation('')" onclick="realTimeChange(this.id)">
    <option value="title">Main Category</op
    <?php echo $option?>
</select>
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat">
    <option value="Non-Use">Sub-Category</option>
    <div id="opt"></div>
</select>
```

PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['val'])){
        $mainCat = $_POST['val'];
        $subOption = '';
        $subName = [];
        include"../storeSQL/sql_Connection.php";
        $sql = "SELECT SUB_CAT FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CAT = '$mainCat' GROUP BY SUB_CAT";
        $getQuery = $connection->query($sql);
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $getQuery->fetch_array()){
        $subName[$i] = $row['SUB_CAT'];
        $subOption .= "<option value='$subName[$i]'>$subName[$i]</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo $subOption;
}
```

Comment: You have unfinished HTML tags.  Also, why is there a `<div>` in your `<select>`?  That should only contain `<option>` tags (or groups thereof, but not in a `<div>`).  When you debug in your browser, what is returned from the server?

Comment: @David, i used alert(val) and its blank. Maybe the sql query is wrong I will have a look at that. The reason why I added the div is because I dont know how to implement the echoed <option> from php.The html tags is finished i just copied half of the div will update it.

Comment: @David I tried echoing a plain text from php to see if anything is returning back, but it still balnk so I dont think its anything to do with the sql queries

Comment: As you are not sending any key here, this php code will always fail and not go to if block

Answer (score 0):

Use key value pair inside `send` function

```
 hr.send("val="+val);
```

And for now use `sub_cat` to append `option` tag

```
  document.getElementById("sub_cat").innerHTML = return_data;
```

And then add first option also before return_data

As you are not sending any key here, this below code will always fail and not go to if block

```
 if(isset($_POST['val'])){
```

Comment: Ok will try, why do i need "val="+val? shouldnt just val work fine?
Also could you go in more detaisl what you mean by
"And then add first option also before return_data"

Comment: It didnt work, but I understood what you meant with hr.send("val="+val) as i had no key to parse to $_POST.

However it still didnt work. nothing was passed over, I tried echoing a test outside the if(isset) and it did work. So somethign is wrong with passing the 'val' :(

Comment: Try `echo "test";exit;` in php end ?

Comment: Also try `hr.send("val=test");`

Comment: hmm inside the if doesnt work, outside the if works.

Comment: Still nothing. I dont get whats happening, outside the if it works fine. the val key is not set for some weird reason.